# CSS framework used by Vue.js website

Tags: css-frameworks

Does anyone have any idea of the CSS framework used by Vue.js website?
I want to use the theme on my website. It's so awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in their [style.css](https://vuejs.org/css/index.css) they are NOT using any framework. It's 100% their code.

The only 3rd party libraries they use are:

- [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)
- [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)
- styles for Algolia's search

[image]